401 (Unauthorized) Request Id when calling Get-DataGatewayCluster with a service principal
Currently trying to use a service principal in order to check power BI connection status
Connect-DataGatewayServiceAccount -ApplicationId $xx -ClientSecret $xx  -Tenant "xx"
$scopeLevel = "Organization"

Get-DataGatewayCluster -Scope $scopeLevel

I am getting the error below
Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized) Request Id:
Does suggest a permission issue, however the service principal is a global admin in Azure, not sure what other permission may be required.
Is there any other way to use a service principal with
Login-DataGatewayServiceAccount 


Read following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/datagateway.profile/connect-datagatewayserviceaccount?view=datagateway-ps#description  Also check logs : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/data-integration/gateway/service-gateway-tshoot#troubleshooting-tools
